# Preamble is empty for (new Utf8Encoding()).GetPreamble() - weird

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, utf-8

Can anyone explain the difference between calling GetPreamble() on a newly instantiated utf8 encoding as opposed to the public ones available from the Encoding class?

```
byte[] p1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble();
byte[] p2 = new UTF8Encoding().GetPreamble();
```

p1 is the normal 3 byte utf-8 preamble, but p2 ends up being empty, which seems very wrong.

Comment: Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8").GetPreamble() works fine.

Comment: MarcosMeli answered your question, yes?  You should accept his answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference is that the UTF8 property of Enconding is created this way

```
new UTF8Encoding(true)
```

this indicates that encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier = true so the 3 byte preamble is there

and your call to the default constructor

```
new UTF8Encoding()
```

that is equivalent to

```
new UTF8Encoding(false)
```

To get same results:

```
byte[] p1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble();
byte[] p2 = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetPreamble();
```

Comment: I got some problems with that a time ago, glad that it helps :)

Comment: Also note that some .NET classes, like `System.IO.StreamWriter`, actually use `new UTF8Encoding(false, true)` by default. That's different from the `Encoding.UTF8` property, as is evident from the above.

Comment: It's pretty ridiculous that `Encoding.UTF8` doesn't use the default constructor `new UTF8Encoding()`...

Comment: No... the fact that UTF-8 has a BOM at all is ridiculous

Answer (score 2):

So my code that gets all know preambles looks like this now:

```
var preambles = new Dictionary<string, byte[]>();
foreach (var encodingInfo in Encoding.GetEncodings()) {
    Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(encodingInfo.Name);
    var preamble = encoding.GetPreamble();
    if (preamble != null && preamble.Length > 0)
        preambles.Add(encodingInfo.Name, preamble);
}
```

Turns out there arent a lot of them

```
utf-16      [2] 255 254
unicodeFFFE [2] 254 255
utf-32      [4] 255 254 0 0
utf-32BE    [4] 0 0 254 255
utf-8       [3] 239 187 191
```

This way I can write code that safely converts a byte array with an optional preamble to a string just by supplying a default encoder for the ones without a preamble. Yay

Comment: It's odd how there is apparently a BOM for UTF-7, but the .net framework has no support for it at all.